# CD drive always available in a laptop

Tags: optical-drive

How can I make the CD drive always available in a laptop, even when it is running on batteries?

Comment: Are you saying your CD/DVD drive doesn't work on battery? Usually in new laptops it's an option to turn off and there is a Tray Icon to enable/disable CD/DVD.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work on batteries, or maybe it is just taking too long to load. It is not showing on the windows explorer. It is a Dell E6410. As soon as I plug in the power supply, it gets recognized, added and able to work.

Comment: you might check in the device properties to see if there is an option there to turn it off to save power (and if it is enabled)

Comment: I would also check in your start menu and in the System Tray (the area near the clock) to see if there is an application for configuring the DVD drive. Usually it's some 3rd party piece of software.